# how to fix lingpipe java error

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, nlp, lingpipe

I open the lingpipe under existing ant-buildfile option then create a package
put the PolarityBasic.java into the package
 I did change the `mPolarityDir=new file("Desktop/POLARITY_DIR/txt_sentoken")` or even create a string contain the file, still the same error

```
Data Directory=POLARITY_DIR/txt_sentoken
Thrown: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/web/download.html    lingpipe-4.1.0

Answer (score 1):

The relative path needs to exist from the directory in which you invoke the command.